# Ordenamiento de coordenadas en función de la X e Y

Tags: matlab, ordenar

Estoy haciendo un programa en matlab, en el cual, en una de sus partes necesito ordenar las coordenadas de una serie de puntos (97puntos) adjunto foto:

[![conjunto de puntos][1]][1]

el ordenamiento sería para comprobar las posiciones teórica de los puntos, las cuales las tengo en una lista, con las que ha dado en el experimento para ello sería conveniente ordenarlos con las coordenadas de menor "X" y menor "Y" a las de mayor, o viceversa, cualquier tipo de orden sería valido, lo que se intenta es hacer un barrido por columnas, también sería válido por filas, pero no se como hacer esto último. Por el momento, el método burbuja no me sale y probando varias opciones con la función "sort" tampoco me lo hace, al código del método burbuja le intenté implementar un AND después OR para que cogiera la segunda coordenada "Y" y no funcionó, por si os vale de algo os dejo el código que sólo ordena por la primera coordenada "X", en el código a1=X y b1=Y, si alguien me puede ayudar lo agradecería.
Un saludo!

```
for i=1:96
 for j=1:96
     if (a1(j)>a1(j+1))  
         temp1=a1(j);
         temp2=b1(j);
         a1(j)=a1(j+1);
         b1(j)=b1(j+1);
         a1(j+1)=temp1;
         b1(j+1)=temp2;
      end
 end
end
```

Añado un ejemplo de lo que tengo y como debería de quedar,tengo los 97 puntos de los cuales sólo pongo unos cuantos para que se vea lo que quiero hacer...

```
-76.4792  -31.1667
-76.3508  -15.7762
-76.3086   -0.4883
-76.6532   14.6270
-76.5524   29.8488
-61.0560  -30.8513
-61.3170   30.3125
-60.9375  -46.2500
-61.0282  -15.3730
-60.9375   -0.3125
-61.1207   14.9246
-61.2500   45.0810
-46.1422   30.2909
-45.7589  -61.2946
-45.9821  -45.8929
-45.8836  -30.3341
-45.7258  -15.4335
-46.0352   -0.1172
-45.7500   15.2083
-46.1830   45.1339
-46.1806   60.3588
```

Los puntos deberían de quedar ordenados de tal manera que fuesen primero los puntos con menor (X,Y) a la vez, es decir, sobre la gráfica de puntos de arriba sería como ordenarlos por columna de puntos, el resultado sería:

```
-76.4792  -31.1667
-76.3508  -15.7762
-76.3086  -0.4883
-76.6532  14.6270
-76.5524  29.8488
-60.9375 -46.2500
-61.0560 -30.8513
-61.0282 -15.3730
-60.9375 -0.3125
-61.1207 14.9246
-61.3170 30.3125
-61.2500 45.0810
-45.7589 -61.2946
-45.9821 -45.8929
-45.8836 -30.3341
-45.7258 -15.4335
-46.0352 -0.1172
-45.7500 15.2083
-46.1422 30.2909
-46.1830 45.1339
-46.1806 60.3588
```

Como vemos el primer punto, no es el que menor X, pero si es el que tiene las dos coordenadas (X,Y) menores. Para que os hagáis una idea en el gráfico debería quedar en ese orden:

[![ordenado][2]][2]

El conjunto de puntos teóricos sería:

```
   -30    75
   -15    75
     0    75
    15    75
    30    75
   -45    60
   -30    60
   -15    60
     0    60
    15    60
    30    60
    45    60
   -60    45
   -45    45
   -30    45
   -15    45
     0    45
    15    45
    30    45
    45    45
    60    45
   -75    30
   -60    30
   -45    30
   -30    30
   -15    30
     0    30
    15    30
    30    30
    45    30
    60    30
    75    30
   -75    15
   -60    15
   -45    15
   -30    15
   -15    15
     0    15
    15    15
    30    15
    45    15
    60    15
    75    15
   -75     0
   -60     0
   -45     0
   -30     0
   -15     0
     0     0
    15     0
    30     0
    45     0
    60     0
    75     0
   -75   -15
   -60   -15
   -45   -15
   -30   -15
   -15   -15
     0   -15
    15   -15
    30   -15
    45   -15
    60   -15
    75   -15
   -75   -30
   -60   -30
   -45   -30
   -30   -30
   -15   -30
     0   -30
    15   -30
    30   -30
    45   -30
    60   -30
    75   -30
   -60   -45
   -45   -45
   -30   -45
   -15   -45
     0   -45
    15   -45
    30   -45
    45   -45
    60   -45
   -45   -60
   -30   -60
   -15   -60
     0   -60
    15   -60
    30   -60
    45   -60
   -30   -75
   -15   -75
     0   -75
    15   -75
    30   -75
```

El conjunto de puntos experimentales sería:

````
 -76.4792  -31.1667
  -76.3508  -15.7762
  -76.3086   -0.4883
  -76.6532   14.6270
  -76.5524   29.8488
  -61.0560  -30.8513
  -61.3170   30.3125
  -60.9375  -46.2500
  -61.0282  -15.3730
  -60.9375   -0.3125
  -61.1207   14.9246
  -61.2500   45.0810
  -46.1422   30.2909
  -45.7589  -61.2946
  -45.9821  -45.8929
  -45.8836  -30.3341
  -45.7258  -15.4335
  -46.0352   -0.1172
  -45.7500   15.2083
  -46.1830   45.1339
  -46.1806   60.3588
  -30.6250  -76.4062
  -30.5603  -45.3772
  -30.9115   45.5208
  -31.1161   60.6250
  -30.8984   75.3906
  -30.5556  -60.8912
  -30.5580  -30.4911
  -30.4526  -15.1832
  -30.4095    0.2263
  -30.5580   15.1339
  -30.6250   30.0000
  -15.5078  -76.0352
  -15.6250   60.6250
  -15.8871   75.6754
  -15.3664  -60.9159
  -15.3125  -45.6250
  -15.2546  -30.3356
  -15.5603  -15.4203
  -15.4087    0.0962
  -15.5435   15.2310
  -15.5580   30.4911
  -15.6250   45.6250
    0.0536  -75.9732
   -0.0625  -60.9375
   -0.1442  -45.1683
   -0.1786  -15.3125
   -0.3125   30.6250
   -0.6250   45.5440
   -0.3233   60.7004
   -0.4087   75.8173
         0  -30.0000
         0         0
         0   15.3846
   14.7991   60.9375
   14.8148   75.7060
   15.2344  -76.0352
   15.2708  -60.6667
   15.3125  -45.0000
   15.0000  -30.0810
   15.5556  -14.9884
   15.2750    0.5125
   15.0000   15.6250
   14.9330   30.4911
   15.1157   45.6829
   30.3906  -76.0352
   30.5833  -45.4167
   30.3009  -29.7569
   30.4526  -14.8168
   30.1515   15.1420
   30.2500   30.7708
   30.3333   45.8333
   30.2083   60.7060
   30.0000   75.8654
   30.6250  -60.5440
   30.5580    0.4911
   45.6250  -60.6667
   45.6250  -14.8558
   45.6481   30.8449
   45.4241   45.9375
   45.6250  -45.3846
   45.7812  -30.0446
   45.9375    0.2679
   45.7692   15.7933
   45.5469   60.9896
   60.8272  -45.3309
   60.6944   30.4977
   60.3233   45.8728
   60.9375  -30.3125
   60.9483  -14.9461
   60.7692    0.3846
   60.6944   15.6366
   76.1364  -30.2936
   76.1830  -14.6875
   76.1343    0.6366
   75.9491   15.5671
   76.2500   30.8654
```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hno1.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCAAA.png
````

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Porque no te saliio? ordenas primero por X y a misma X por Y... ponele... usando burbuja...

Comment: por lo que veo, te falta analizar en tu bucle for que ocurre si la coordenada X de j y de j+1 son iguales. Si es asi, tendras que comprobar la coordenada Y, y en funcion de eso, ordenar. En general, tu algoritmo estaria incompleto para el caso que comentas

Comment: Buenas! Es bastante improbable que sean iguales ya que las coordenadas son números de 3 decimales, igualmente gracias por la observación!!

Comment: Tu pregunta es cada vez mas confusa.. y si ademas de toda esa explicacion, nos das un ejemplo clarisimo!!!! (con datos y todo) de como tienen que quedar ordenada las cosas, y como vienen??? porque la respuesta que te dieron, esta correcta...

Comment: @gbianchi la respuesta que me dieron no es correcta ya que no ordena los pares de coordenadas (X, Y) primero los de menor X y luego los de menor Y pero sin perder la relación de cada punto, es decir, no me vale la coordenada  X de un punto con la coordenada Y de otro, el ejemplo que doy es la representación gráfica de la nube de puntos que obtengo en el experimento, los datos no están ordenados, simplemente al representarlos se ven ordenados....

Comment: Y el ejemplo???? porque no podes agregar un ejemplo claro?

Comment: @gbianchi edité la pregunta con un ejemplo a ver si se entiende mejor, saludos!

Comment: Tu orden todavia queda menos claro en las imagenes que subis (hubiera sido mejor que mostraras datos, asi se podian copiar)... bajo que concepto el primero va primero?? porque no hay una logica consistente en el orden que mostras... es como magico...

Comment: @gbianchi como bien digo es el que tiene ambas coordenadas (X Y) menores, edito de nuevo a ver si entiende el orden

Comment: y entonces porque no es burbuja donde x sea menor que x+1 Y (notese el Y) y sea menor que y+1?? no entiendo que falla ahi, si entiendo el problema con la respuesta....

Comment: Simplemente utilizando el operador "Y" en el método burbuja no lo hace bien, ya lo intenté.

Comment: No entiendo la lógica de ordenamiento. Porqué `-60.9375 -46.2500` sería el menor punto ??

Comment: @Yussef si te fijas en la figura y el ordenamiento que quiero hacer barriendo columnas el -60.9375 -45.2500, sería el punto "6" y el -61.0560 -30.8513 sería el "7" y así sucesivamente...como bien dije expuse sólo una muestra de los datos, a lo mejor eso te llevó a confusión.

Comment: @Yussef te edito los datos para que veas los 5 primero datos que faltaban

Comment: En tu pregunta expones una lista de puntos, luego dices que esa lista ordenada debería quedara como se muestra en la segunda lista de puntos. Mi pregunta es que bajo que criterio el punto `-60.9375 -46.2500` lo has colocado primero. Tu quieres ordenar algo bidimensional en un arreglo unidimensional, para eso necesitas de un criterio. Tu dices que primero los de menor X, pero resulta que  `-60.9375` no es el menor X...entonces no me queda nada claro

Comment: @Yussef buenas tardes, siento el lío de la cuestión, a ver, en el caso teórico tengo que la coordenada "X" del 1-5 es 75.0000 y del punto 6-12 es 60.0000, al hacer el experimento obtengo las coordenadas que muestro, en principio sería ordenarlas de menor X  primero y menor Y después, haciendo el barrido por columnas que describo, pero los resultados dan los números expuestos y dentro de la columna me varía la coordenada X, como bien dices, y a veces es mayor la coordenada "X"que la siguiente en la columna, ¿habría alguna forma de hacer el ordenamiento que muestro en la figura por columnas?

Comment: @Yussef y si no es posible hacerlo estoy abierto a otro tipo de ordenamiento que se pueda hacer, a mi no se me ocurre nada. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

no se si entendi bien la pregunta, pero lo que quieres hacer es primero ordenar por X mayores, y una vez que este ordenado por X, ordenar por Y?
si es ese el caso , lo que tendrias que verificar es que cuando sean iguales ordene por Y. ejemplo

```
 for i=1:96
     for j=1:96
         if (a1(j)>a1(j+1))  
             temp1=a1(j);
             temp2=b1(j);
             a1(j)=a1(j+1);
             b1(j)=b1(j+1);
             a1(j+1)=temp1;
             b1(j+1)=temp2;
             elseif (a1(j) == a1(j+1)
                if (b1(j) > b1(j+1)
                temp2 = b1(j);
                b1(j)=b1(j+1);
                b1(j+1)=temp2;
                end
          end
         
             
     end
    end
```

Comment: Supongo que en la segunda parte solo moves b1, porque al ser el mismo a1, no tiene sentido moverlo, no??? siempre explica esos detalles, capaz que alguien no lo entiende asi...

Comment: Buenas, te agradezco el esfuerzo de antemano pero no me vale, me intentaré explicar otra vez, yo tengo una nube de puntos de los cuales necesito que X e Y, en este caso a1 y b1, tengan su correspondencia, es decir, que no los ordene en la posición uno el que tenga menor X y menor Y, sino que tiene que ser el número uno el que las 2 coordenadas sea la menor, no que coja la X de un punto y la Y de otro, no se si me explico....

Comment: Edité la pregunta a ver si ahora se entiende mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Ordenar por `X` y luego por `Y` solo te funciona para los puntos teóricos **porque están perfectamente alineados**, de lo contrario no va a resultar, porque un punto experimental puede estar mas a la izquierda (y será menor) que otro punto que estas declarando como mayor

Lo que entiendo que tu quieres **no tiene nada que ver con ordenamiento**, entiendo que quieres parear los puntos teóricos con los experimentales, es decir a cada punto experimental le corresponderá uno y solo un punto teórico.

Este es un problema de búsqueda en profundidad y como tal se puede resolver utilizando una *Pila* y un *While*. La idea central es que tienes tus puntos experimentales en una Pila de puntos. Sacas uno y lo asocias con el punto teórico más cercano, luego pruebas con el siguiente punto experimental. Si existe un siguiente punto que se asocia mejor (es más cercano) a otro ya asociado previamente, hay que sacar el anterior y volver a ingresarlo a la pila.

*No sobra señalar que la distancia de 2 puntos se calcula usando Pitágoras.*

Luego el ordenamiento de los puntos los da el orden de los puntos teóricos, ya que estamos pareando contra él. Es decir, el primer punto será el asociado al primer punto teórico.

Entonces basta que los puntos teóricos los coloques según el orden que tu preestableciste para que se impriman correctamente

```
teorico = struct('x', [-75 -75 -75 -75 -75 -60 -60 -60 -60 -60 -60 -60 -45 -45 -45 -45 -45 -45 -45 -45 -45 -30 -30 -30 -30 -30 -30 -30 -30 -30 -30 -30 -15 -15 -15 -15 -15 -15 -15 -15 -15 -15 -15 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 75 75 75 75 75], 'y', [-30 -15 0 15 30 -45 -30 -15 0 15 30 45 -60 -45 -30 -15 0 15 30 45 60 -75 -60 -45 -30 -15 0 15 30 45 60 75 -75 -60 -45 -30 -15 0 15 30 45 60 75 -75 -60 -45 -30 -15 0 15 30 45 60 75 -75 -60 -45 -30 -15 0 15 30 45 60 75 -75 -60 -45 -30 -15 0 15 30 45 60 75 -60 -45 -30 -15 0 15 30 45 60 -45 -30 -15 0 15 30 45 -30 -15 0 15 30]);

a1 = [-76.4792, -76.3508, -76.3086, -76.6532, -76.5524, -60.9375, -61.0560, -61.0282, -60.9375, -61.1207, -61.3170, -61.2500, -45.7589, -45.9821, -45.8836, -45.7258, -46.0352, -45.7500, -46.1422, -46.1830, -46.1806];
b1 = [-31.1667, -15.7762, -0.4883, 14.6270, 29.8488, -46.2500, -30.8513, -15.3730, -0.3125, 14.9246, 30.3125, 45.0810, -61.2946, -45.8929, -30.3341, -15.4335, -0.1172, 15.2083, 30.2909, 45.1339, 60.3588];

guardados = struct('x', [], 'y', [], 'd', []);

puntos = struct('x', a1, 'y', b1);

while ~isempty(puntos.x)
    p2.x = puntos.x(end);
    p2.y = puntos.y(end);
    puntos.x(end) = [];
    puntos.y(end) = [];
    
    for t = 1:numel(teorico.x)
        p1.x = teorico.x(t);
        p1.y = teorico.y(t);
        d = sqrt((p2.x - p1.x)^2 + (p2.y - p1.y)^2);
        
        if (numel(guardados) < t || isempty(guardados(t).d) || d < guardados(t).d)
            guardados(t).x = p2.x;
            guardados(t).y = p2.y;
            guardados(t).d = d;
        elseif (numel(guardados) >= t && d < guardados(t).d)
            puntos.x(end+1) = guardados(t).x;
            puntos.y(end+1) = guardados(t).y;
            guardados(t).x = p2.x;
            guardados(t).y = p2.y;
            guardados(t).d = d;
        end
    end
end

for t = 1:numel(guardados)
    disp(['  x: ', num2str(guardados(t).x), '   y: ', num2str(guardados(t).y), '  d: ',  num2str(guardados(t).d)]);
    disp(' ');
end
```

Salida:

```
  x: -76.4792   y: -31.1667  d: 1.8839
 
  x: -76.3508   y: -15.7762  d: 1.5579
 
  x: -76.3086   y: -0.4883  d: 1.3967
 
  x: -76.6532   y: 14.627  d: 1.6948
 
  x: -76.5524   y: 29.8488  d: 1.5597
 
  x: -60.9375   y: -46.25  d: 1.5625
 
  x: -61.056   y: -30.8513  d: 1.3564
 
  x: -61.0282   y: -15.373  d: 1.0938
 
  x: -60.9375   y: -0.3125  d: 0.98821
 
  x: -61.1207   y: 14.9246  d: 1.1232
 
  x: -61.317   y: 30.3125  d: 1.3536
 
  x: -61.25   y: 45.081  d: 1.2526
 
  x: -45.7589   y: -61.2946  d: 1.5006
 
  x: -45.9821   y: -45.8929  d: 1.3273
 
  x: -45.8836   y: -30.3341  d: 0.94465
 
  x: -45.7258   y: -15.4335  d: 0.8454
 
  x: -46.0352   y: -0.1172  d: 1.0418
 
  x: -45.75   y: 15.2083  d: 0.77839
 
  x: -46.1422   y: 30.2909  d: 1.1787
 
  x: -46.183   y: 45.1339  d: 1.1906
 
  x: -46.1806   y: 60.3588  d: 1.2339
 
  x: -45.7589   y: -61.2946  d: 20.8849
 
  x: -45.7589   y: -61.2946  d: 15.812
 
  x: -45.9821   y: -45.8929  d: 16.007
 
  x: -45.8836   y: -30.3341  d: 15.8871
 
  x: -45.7258   y: -15.4335  d: 15.7318
 
  x: -46.0352   y: -0.1172  d: 16.0356
 
  x: -45.75   y: 15.2083  d: 15.7514
 
  x: -46.1422   y: 30.2909  d: 16.1448
 
  x: -46.183   y: 45.1339  d: 16.1836
 
  x: -46.1806   y: 60.3588  d: 16.1846
 
  x: -46.1806   y: 60.3588  d: 21.8215
 
  x: -45.7589   y: -61.2946  d: 33.6741
 
  x: -45.7589   y: -61.2946  d: 30.7861
 
  x: -45.9821   y: -45.8929  d: 30.995
 
  x: -45.8836   y: -30.3341  d: 30.8854
 
  x: -45.7258   y: -15.4335  d: 30.7289
 
  x: -46.0352   y: -0.1172  d: 31.0354
 
  x: -45.75   y: 15.2083  d: 30.7507
 
  x: -46.1422   y: 30.2909  d: 31.1436
 
  x: -46.183   y: 45.1339  d: 31.1833
 
  x: -46.1806   y: 60.3588  d: 31.1827
 
  x: -46.1806   y: 60.3588  d: 34.447
 
  x: -45.7589   y: -61.2946  d: 47.7673
 
  x: -45.7589   y: -61.2946  d: 45.7772
 
  x: -45.9821   y: -45.8929  d: 45.9908
 
  x: -45.8836   y: -30.3341  d: 45.8848
 
  x: -45.7258   y: -15.4335  d: 45.7279
 
  x: -46.0352   y: -0.1172  d: 46.0353
 
  x: -45.75   y: 15.2083  d: 45.7505
 
  x: -46.1422   y: 30.2909  d: 46.1431
 
  x: -46.183   y: 45.1339  d: 46.1832
 
  x: -46.1806   y: 60.3588  d: 46.182
 
  x: -46.1806   y: 60.3588  d: 48.446
 
  x: -45.7589   y: -61.2946  d: 62.2855
 
  x: -45.7589   y: -61.2946  d: 60.7727
 
  x: -45.9821   y: -45.8929  d: 60.9886
 
  x: -45.8836   y: -30.3341  d: 60.8845
 
  x: -45.7258   y: -15.4335  d: 60.7273
 
  x: -46.0352   y: -0.1172  d: 61.0353
 
  x: -45.75   y: 15.2083  d: 60.7504
 
  x: -46.1422   y: 30.2909  d: 61.1429
 
  x: -46.183   y: 45.1339  d: 61.1831
 
  x: -46.1806   y: 60.3588  d: 61.1817
 
  x: -46.1806   y: 60.3588  d: 62.9081
 
  x: -45.7589   y: -61.2946  d: 76.9886
 
  x: -45.7589   y: -61.2946  d: 75.77
 
  x: -45.9821   y: -45.8929  d: 75.9873
 
  x: -45.8836   y: -30.3341  d: 75.8843
 
  x: -45.7258   y: -15.4335  d: 75.727
 
  x: -46.0352   y: -0.1172  d: 76.0353
 
  x: -45.75   y: 15.2083  d: 75.7503
 
  x: -46.1422   y: 30.2909  d: 76.1428
 
  x: -46.183   y: 45.1339  d: 76.1831
 
  x: -46.1806   y: 60.3588  d: 76.1814
 
  x: -46.1806   y: 60.3588  d: 77.5748
 
  x: -45.7589   y: -61.2946  d: 90.7681
 
  x: -45.9821   y: -45.8929  d: 90.9865
 
  x: -45.8836   y: -30.3341  d: 90.8842
 
  x: -45.7258   y: -15.4335  d: 90.7268
 
  x: -46.0352   y: -0.1172  d: 91.0353
 
  x: -45.75   y: 15.2083  d: 90.7502
 
  x: -46.1422   y: 30.2909  d: 91.1427
 
  x: -46.183   y: 45.1339  d: 91.1831
 
  x: -46.1806   y: 60.3588  d: 91.1813
 
  x: -45.9821   y: -45.8929  d: 105.9859
 
  x: -45.8836   y: -30.3341  d: 105.8841
 
  x: -45.7258   y: -15.4335  d: 105.7267
 
  x: -46.0352   y: -0.1172  d: 106.0353
 
  x: -45.75   y: 15.2083  d: 105.7502
 
  x: -46.1422   y: 30.2909  d: 106.1426
 
  x: -46.183   y: 45.1339  d: 106.1831
 
  x: -45.8836   y: -30.3341  d: 120.8841
 
  x: -45.7258   y: -15.4335  d: 120.7266
 
  x: -46.0352   y: -0.1172  d: 121.0353
 
  x: -45.75   y: 15.2083  d: 120.7502
 
  x: -46.1422   y: 30.2909  d: 121.1425
```

Comment: ante todo muchas gracias por la respuesta, ya ví que en "JS" te hace el ordenamiento deseado, pero lo probaste en matlab? a mi no me sale el mismo orden que en Javascript, a que puede deberse???

Comment: @yul72 Lo que estaba mal es el código javascript :S. Lo corregí y agregue unas mejoras al de Matlab.  Considera que los puntos que has colocado no están ordenados correctamente, por ejemplo el (-76.6532 ,14.6270) es el de menor X por lo que debe ir primero

Comment: A mi al ejecutar el JS anterior me daba justo el orden que está expuesto en la figura con los puntos exactos, no me salía con el código de matlab, en el nuevo código si que están ordenados por el menor "X" pero no barren la columna en el orden de la figura. Perdón por las molestias

Comment: @yul72 Es que eso es justamente lo que te he tratado de explicar todo el tiempo. Tu dices (y te cito literal): `sería ordenarlas de menor X primero y menor Y después`, el código tal como está hace justamente eso.

Comment: Según lo que entiendo ahora, es que tu quieres otra cosa distinta. Tu quieres parear los puntos experimentales con los teóricos: "Será el primer punto el más cercano al punto (1) teórico, el segundo el mas cercando al (2) teórico y así sucesivamente". Si es así debes colocar los puntos teóricos, porque el algoritmo es dependiente a esos puntos

Comment: Muchas gracias! los puntos teóricos ya los tengo en el algoritmo pero tampoco se como hacer o si hay alguna función para que encuentre puntos "cercanos" de dos conjuntos, por eso intenté hacerlo como comenté, lo que pasó fue que en el punto 1, como bien dices, la coordenada X no es menor que la del punto 4.

Comment: Creo haber entendido lo que quieres. La solución que se me ocurre requiere de los pts teóricos. Entonces necesito que edites tu pregunta y los agregues

Comment: Ya están puestos los puntos teóricos y del experimento, como decías se trata de hacer la correlación entre ellos y ver la diferencia.

Comment: Gran aportación y explicación, muchisimas gracias Yussef